# Set Disable "Delete After Import" in Image Capture As Default

Tags: image-capture

Is there a way to disable "Delete After Import" (and perhaps enable "Keep Originals by default) in Image Capture by default, at least for a specific phone? I always wish to copy (but not remove) my photos using the program from my iPhone to my Mac, but always forget to disable the option. I am using macOS 10.13.6 with iOS 15.3.1 (iPhone 13).

Answer (score 0):

It ought to just remember those settings per device.
Example showing 3 devices connected, each with different settings -

[image]